# Amend a svn migration to git

Tags: git, svn

Sometime in the past, prior to my start with my current employer, a devops engineer—who will remain anonymous—seems to have taken a direct and coarse route to migration from SVN to git. My assessment is that the actions taken amounted to:

```sh
svn export repos /tmp/repos
cd /tmp/repos
git init
git add --all
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
```

Of course, there is no history. Many repositories appear to have sprang from metal on March 5, 2018.

What course of action could I take to "amend" these git repos with the SVN history—if I even still have access to those repos—after the fact? Any guides out there?

Or should I just shake my fist in the air every time I see the annotated code and curse the loss? Given git's SHA and commit tree model, I suspect I'm going to be shaking my fist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you still have the SVN repository, convert it with [`svn2git`](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git), make that repository an upstream, and then rewrite your repo on top of it.

First, make a backup of your repo just in case.

Once you've done the `svn2git` conversion, switch to your other repo and make svn2git a remote.

```
$ git remote add svn <path to the svn2git repo>
$ git fetch svn

A - B - C [svn/master]

D - E - F [master]
```

D here is the original `svn export` commit.

Now can rebase on top of svn/master, but `git filter-repo` might do a better job with something this complex. [Replace](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace) the old `svn export` commit with the tip of `svn/master`. Then have `git filter-repo` rewrite history to make it permanent.

```
$ git replace D C
$ git filter-repo --force

A - B - C [svn/master]
         \
          E1 - F1 [master]
```

Comment: i'm going to give this some serious consideration... queried our devops team... "Gimme the keys."

Comment: @javafueled You should be able to do try this locally without only read-access to SVN.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the SVN repos locally, yet. But I was told the repos are online in read-only mode. I hope to be able to `checkout` a repo for experimenting soon.

Comment: Well, a downvote on the question itself. Damn. No comment or reason.

Comment: This worked like a charm @schwern. Getting the repo and resolving issues with svn and `filter-repo` on my Mac are stories of permission exploits, shell mastery, and network switching; more exciting than following your concise guide! Thank you!